# $f(x)=\begin{cases} 0, x\in I \cap [0,1] \\ \frac{1}{q} , x=\frac{p}{q}, p,q \in \mathbb{N}, (p,q)=1\end{cases}$ Is $f$ measurable? Continuous?

Tags: calculus, measure-theory

$$ f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R} \\ \text{defined as:}\\f(x)=\begin{cases} 0, x\in I \cap [0,1]  \\ \frac{1}{q} , x=\frac{p}{q}, p,q \in \mathbb{N}, (p,q)=1\end{cases}$$

I think and am pretty sure that $(,)$ means that $p,q$ aren't divisable. This function is at first glance similar to the characteristic function of $Q \cap[0,1].$ I have the definition of measurability as $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is measurable iff $A=\{x\in X: f(x)<c\}\in \mathcal{B}(X)$, $\forall c\in \mathbb{R}$. I have difficulties using this definition with this function with $c\in[0,1]$. I know that for a fixed $c$ in this range I would have $A$ as a set of infinity countable points, being a subset of $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$. is this $A\in \mathcal{B}([0,1])?$ I an not sure because it is a countable union of closed sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the set $f^{-1}(\{1/q\})$ with $q$ a positive integer. This is a finite set and its cardinality is $\leq q$.

Let $0<c\leq 1$ and let $n=\lfloor 1/c\rfloor$, then
$$[0,1]\setminus A=\{x\in [0,1]: f(x)\geq c\}=\bigcup_{1\leq q\leq n} f^{-1}(\{1/q\})\quad\mbox{is a finite set}$$
where $A=\{x\in [0,1]: f(x)< c\}$.  Hence $A$ is $[0,1]$ minus a finite set which means that $A\in \mathcal{B}([0,1])$.

P.S. $f$ is not continuous at $\frac{1}{2}$: $f(\frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{2}$ but
$f(x_n)=0\to 0$ for $x_n=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}\in [0,1]\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ for $n\geq 3$.

Comment: That's not infinite, but I don't understand what you are getting to?

Comment: for example if I have $c=\frac{1}{3}$ then $A=\{\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3},\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4},\frac{1}{5},\frac{2}{5},\frac{3}{5},\frac{4}{5}...\}$- a countably infinite number of points on $Q$

Comment: @Bozo Vulicevic Is it clear now?